# AWS CloudWatch selecting first existing field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have two kinds of messages in the AWS CloudWatch and would like to select the first field that has some text in it. For example

Mesasge 1:

```
"message": {
   "message": "I am the first priority"
}
```

Message 2:

```
"message": {
    "err": {
         "message": "I am second priority"
    }
}
```

I would like to have these in a single column of the CloudWatch table depending which one is present. Is there any way to do this? Something like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
fields @timestamp, ispresent(message.message) ? message.message : message.err.message
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently coalesce function is what I needed. It selected the first value that is not null:

```
fields @timestamp, component, coalesce(message.message, message.err.message) as TheMessage
```

More info at [CloudWatch Logs Insights query syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html)